# Recursive Binary Search Tree in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written this code for binary search for an element in a list. 
The code reaches maximum recursion. I can't figure out why.

```
def binary_search(alist, x, left = 0, right = None):
    right = right or len(alist) - 1
    middle = left + (right - left) // 2

    if x == alist[middle]:
        return middle
    elif right < left:
        return -1
    elif x < alist[middle]:
        return binary_search(alist, x, left, middle - 1)
    elif x > alist[middle]: 
        return binary_search(alist, x, middle + 1, right)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    a = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7,8,9,10,11]
    data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8,9,10,11, 12]

for x in data:
    print(binary_search(a, x), end = ' ')
```

Comment: Open and shut case of "why isn't this code working?" close reason.

Comment: Think about what happens when `right == 0`.

Comment: What have you done to try and "figure out why"?

Answer (score 0):

If you try searching for an `x` that's smaller than the left-most element of `alist`, sooner or later you'll get `right=0`. Since `0` is a false value, the first row of `binary_search` will reset it to `len(alist) - 1`, and start the whole process over, which will at some point fail due the the maximum recursion hit.

You can solve this by only explicitly replacing `None` with the length of the list and not any false value (such as `0`):

```
right = right if right is not None else len(alist) - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For a value that is larger than the highest value in the list, right will reach the size of the list. In that case you compute right to be len(aList) - 1 which brings it back to left == right and will make it go again with left = len(aList)-1 and right = len(aList).  ==> Infinite recursion.

You should compute middle = (left+right) // 2

You could also do it like this:

```
def binSearch(value,array,offset=0):
    if len(array) == 0 : return None
    i = len(array)//2
    if array[i] < value : return binSearch(value,array[i+1:],i+1+offset)
    if array[i] > value : return binSearch(value,array[:i],offset)
    return i + offset
```